# Stored procedure not executing from c# window application

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, sql-server-express

I have a stored procedure name `SaveNewSupplier`. Just parsing xml and insert values. But when I pass the parameter manually to execute stored procedure it works fine and values properly inserted. 
I have added it on button click event, here is my code

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SalesRetailConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SaveNewSupplier", sqlConnection);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

String xml = "<DocumentElement><Table1><SupName>Madan</SupName><Code>dsad</Code><Type>dddd</Type><Address>5555</Address><Country>india</Country><City>Kol</City><State>WB</State><Nationality>In</Nationality><PhoneNo>00000000</PhoneNo><AlternateNo>ATL</AlternateNo><MobileNo>99999999</MobileNo></Table1></DocumentElement>";

command.Parameters.Add("@pParam", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = xml;
sqlConnection.Open();
int ret = 0;
ret = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlConnection.Close();
```

Here is my app.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="SalesRetailConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\SalesRetail.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

My Stored Procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.SaveNewSupplier
(
    @pParam varchar(max)
)
AS
begin
    declare @SupName varchar(100)
    declare @Code varchar(100)
    declare @Type varchar(100)
    declare @Address varchar(100)
    declare @Country varchar(100)
    declare @City varchar(100)
    declare @State varchar(100)
    declare @Nationality varchar(100)
    declare @PhoneNo varchar(100)
    declare @AlternateNo varchar(100)
    declare @MobileNo varchar(100)

    declare @XMLData XML
    select  @XMLData = @pParam


    select  @SupName = Tbl.Col.value('SupName[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
            @Code = Tbl.Col.value('Code[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
            @Type = Tbl.Col.value('Type[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
            @Address = Tbl.Col.value('Address[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
            @Country = Tbl.Col.value('Country[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
            @City = Tbl.Col.value('City[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
            @State = Tbl.Col.value('State[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
            @Nationality = Tbl.Col.value('Nationality[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
            @PhoneNo = Tbl.Col.value('PhoneNo[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
            @AlternateNo = Tbl.Col.value('AlternateNo[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
            @MobileNo = Tbl.Col.value('MobileNo[1]', 'varchar(100)')
            from    @XMLData.nodes('//Table1') Tbl(Col)

    begin
    insert into tblSupplierMaster(SupName, Code, Type, Address, Country, City, State, Nationality, PhoneNo, AlternateNo, MobileNo)
    values (@SupName, @Code, @Type, @Address, @Country,
            @City, @State, @Nationality, @PhoneNo, @AlternateNo, @MobileNo)
    end
end
```

When I am executing this code `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` returning 1. but no data inserting in database. I don't get the problem.

Thank you.

Comment: where is the source for the stored procedure?

Comment: Sorry but what does this (**command.Parameters.Add("@pParam", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = xml;**) line mean? Do you split parameters in sp?

Comment: Try this: `command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pParam", xml));`

Comment: @PiLHA I have tried this also but doesn't work.

Comment: How do you check that the record is not inserted? Looking at the database through Server Explorer in VS?

Comment: @Steve yes.... from server explorer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your connectionstring use the |DataDirectory| substitution string. This means that your MDF file is searched by the data access code inside the directory BIN\DEBUG or BIN\RELEASE if you have a WinForm application or in the APP_DATA directory if ASP.NET.

There is a common mistake here because the developer add a connection to the Server Explorer that points to the MDF file located in the project folder and then checks the results using this connection while the code updates/inserts/deletes in the BIN\DEBUG file.

Effectively the ExecuteNonQuery returns 1 meaning that a record is inserted. But not where you are looking at

You can resolve this adding the database directly to your SQLExpress through Sql Server Management Studio, change the connection string in your config and then update the connection in Server Explorer.

Comment: But how could I merge this two database?? I want to view only one instance

Comment: Keep the one in the project folder as an empty database to deploy when your application is ready, use Sql Server Management Studio to add your MDF file to the current instance of SQLExpress and fix your connections strings

Comment: I don't have Sql Server Management Studio. I am using VS2010 professional

Comment: You can download free from here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8961 It is useful to handle various administrative tasks that you cannot execute from VS